# How to make PDF fillable?

Tags: python, django, pdf

I have links to unfillable PDFs and I want to make them fillable in my python application.

I could use Adobe SDK for Python, but does this allow me to automate PDF fillability. I just want to create the fillable fields and display the PDF for users to fill out. I have 10,000 PDFs, so I want to just call the API to make them fillable. The fields are different in every PDF.

Adobe's Fill and Sign manual application that works really well. Do they have an API that will mimic this?

[image]

Comment: Try to create a form in django and add all those fields in database and then convert that to pdf instead of filling pdf will be difficult.

Comment: @Println The fields are different in every PDF - there is no consistency.